# Is it possible to parseFloat the whole string?

Tags: javascript, parsefloat

As you know, the javascript's `parseFloat` function works only until it meets an invalid character, so for example

```
parseFloat("10.123") = 10.123
parseFloat("12=zzzz") = 12
parseFloat("z12") = NaN
```

Is there a way or an implementation of parseFloat that would return NaN if the *whole* string is not a valid float number?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
var num = Number(value);
```

Then you can do:

```
if (isNaN(num)) {
    // take proper action
}
```

Comment: This is a better idea than my answer :)

Comment: That's perfect, thanks. I'll have to wait 8 minutes to mark the answer yet :)

Comment: Just be careful about some specific cases, e.g.: `isNaN(parseFloat("")); // true` and `Number("") == 0; // true`

Comment: @exoboy - You don't need to deal with illegal characters with this solution.  Try this and you'll see: var x = Number("#!"); if (isNaN(x)) alert("bad");

Comment: @exoboy - I'm not sure I understand, when I run your example I get NaN for num, which is what I would expect since ")(*(*&()*H3.4" isn't a valid float. Also, you left off an else clause before your second alert call, so perhaps you should test your code ;).  Anyway, no need to get hostile here.

Comment: @exoboy: `Number` doesn't 'coerce' a number out of a string. It's a function to _convert_ a string into a number, _if_ it is a valid number. The question asked to only yield a number if the whole string is a valid number.

Comment: @exoboy: Yes, I do. Do you? "1.23" -> 1.23 = conversion. "kdfj*&$1.23jk" -> 1.23 = coercion. The OP wanted conversion, your answer supplied coercion. Anyway, the votes speak for themselves, as dcp said, no need to get hostile.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe try:

```
var f = parseFloat( someStr );
if( f.toString() != someStr ) {
  // string has other stuff besides the number
}
```

*Update*: Don't do this, use @dcp's method :)

Comment: +1 for providing an answer that solves the problem and then pointing the OP to use an answer you consider better.

Comment: It's indeed a bad way to solve this problem since it won't work with value like "12.5000".

Comment: @HoLyVieR: Yea, it really depends on where your data is coming from. Most languages serializing out values wont pad with zeroes unless you explicitly say so. Since `Number()` solves these sorts of problems (with a few caveats of it's own) there's no need to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
var asFloat = parseFloat("12aa");
if (String(asFloat).length != "12aa".length) {
     // The value is not completely a float
}
else {
     // The value is a float
}
```